# What does $y = Ar^t$ mean?

Tags: education

I keep coming up in this question and its variants in my math tests, but it has not been explained to me so I can't really answer it. As such, I am at risk of failing the year.

An example question is as below:

> Bob bought a farm in 1980. In 2017 he sold it for $500,000 and calculated it rose exponentially at a rate of 4% over that time.
>
> (i) Assuming that it increased in value according to the formula $y = Ar^t$, where $A$ is the purchase price and  $^t$  is the time in years, what was his profit?

As you can see, the values of $A$ and $^t$ are pretty clearly defined, and $y$ is implicitly defined, but nowhere is the value $r$ defined.

So what is $r$ supposed to be, and how would I go about answering this question?

Comment: Where are you using the rate of 4%?

Comment: @KitterCatter the question specifies that

Comment: I am not sure what 'exponentially at a rate of 4%' means. Naively I would do something like $y(t) = A (1.04)^t$.

Comment: @KitterCatter: Yes, but I would have expected the wording to reflect that. When I see exponential in finance I think continuous compounding.

Comment: Usually continuous compounding would result in something like $y(t) = A e^{0.04 t}$.

Comment: @copper.hat And so $r=e^{0.04}$, no?

Comment: @amd: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The $r$ means rate of increase of the price, which is $1 + 4\% = 1.04$.

$$t = 2017 - 1980 = 37 \text{ years}$$
$$y = $500000$$

Now we calculate the value of $A$, which is the purchase price of the farm in 1980.

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
y &=& Ar^t\\
500000&=&A\left(1.04\right)^{37}\\
A&=&\dfrac{500000}{(1.04)^{37}} \\
&\approx&$117148.42
\end{array}$$

Now, the profit is $\text{Selling price} - \text{Purchase price}$:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\text{Profit} &=& $500000 - $117148.42\\
&\approx&$382851.58
\end{array}$$

To clarify, $y = Ar^t$ is an exponential equation. Usually $r$ denotes the rate of increase, or the rate of decrease as $r$ stands for "rate".

Comment: This is standard compounding, but the question specifies an exponential rate.

Comment: Actually, the increase is exponential, not the rate, which is flat.

$1.04^t$ is exponential as $^t$ increases

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is mean by exponential rate, but assuming that it means continuous compounding, we have the formula
$y(t) = A e^{0.04 t}$, with $t$ in years.

Hence $y(2017) = y(1980) e^{0.04 (2017-1980)} = 500000$ from which can compute $y(1980)$. Then the profit is given by $y(2017)-y(1980) \approx 386181$.

Comment: My notation is a bit inconsistent above but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) is:
$$f(x)=ab^x,b>0.$$
Now $b$ can take various values, in particular:
$$b=1+\frac{0.04}{m},m\ne 0$$
Note that when $m=1,2,4,12$, it is the annual, semi-annual, quarterly, monthly [interest compounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest), respectively. For example, for $x\in \mathbb N$:
$$f(x)=a(1+0.04)^x=a\underbrace{(1+0.04)(1+0.04)\cdots (1+0.04)}_{x}\\
f(x)=a\left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)^{2x}=a\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac{0.04}{2}\right)}_{2x}.$$

When $m\to \infty$, the formula of continuous interest compounding becomes:
$$f(x)=\lim_\limits{m\to \infty} a\left(1+\frac{0.04}{m}\right)^{mx}=ae^{0.04x}.$$

=========================================================================

The OP's problem suggests the exponential function $y=Ar^t$. However, it can be interpreted in two ways:
$$y(t)=Ar^t=A(1+0.04)^t=Ag(t)$$
or:
$$y(t)=Ar^t=A(e^{0.04})^t=Ag(t)$$
Note: The first is an ordinary exponential function, while the second is a natural exponential function.

Once it is clarified, the rest is a simple calculation with 
$$\begin{align}y(0)&=A,\\
t&=2017-1980=37,\\
y(37)&=500,000\\
\text{Profit}&=\frac{y(37)}{A}=\frac{500,000}{A}=g(37) \ \ \text{(in percentage of the purchase price)}\\
\text{Profit}&=y(37)-A=\\
&=500,000-\frac{y(37)}{g(37)}=\\
&=500,000-\frac{500,000}{g(37)}\ \ \text{(in dollars)}\end{align}$$